# Which syscall is used for creating of new process/thread on OpenBSD-5.3

Tags: pthreads, clone, system-calls, openbsd

In Linux, 'clone()' syscall is used for creating processes/threads.

On OpenBSD-5.3 using ktrace/kdump I determined that for process creation 'vfork()' syscall is used, and for thread creation - 'tfork()'.

I have two questions:

1. Is my statement correct?
2. Shouldn't 'vfork()' and 'tfork()' finally use a single system call like 'clone()'?

Comment: There should be a `fork()` syscall, probably different than `vfork()`. `vfork()` is a possibly restricted version of `fork()`, meant to be used only if you instantly call `execve()` or `_exit()`. On OSes that have been ported to !MMU platforms, it is definitely different than `fork()`.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of clone(), but I would use `fork(2)` to create a new process and `pthread_create(3)` to create a new thread. These are portable.

Comment: Yes, it is. Not sure if that matters to OP.